# correct http status code for multiple records found

Tags: rest

i am trying to figure out what would be the right http status code for below scenario.

we are coming up with new api, where in api will search a user based on firstname, lastname, dob, phone number etc. if no records are found we are sending 404, and if only 1 record is found its 200. but trying to figure out what would be appropriate status if more than 1 record is found. i cant find appropriate header code for that. it cant be 200 or 400 or 500. its neither a error or bad request.

if more than 1 record is found, we have to ask the consumer api to send more info to find out correct record.

do we have any appropriate header for above use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we are coming up with new api, where in api will search a user based on firstname, lastname, dob, phone number etc. if no records are found we are sending 404, and if only 1 record is found its 200. but trying to figure out what would be appropriate status if more than 1 record is found. i cant find appropriate header code for that. it cant be 200 or 400 or 500. its neither a error or bad request.

When you searched for an answer on Google (or here at stack exchange), and got back multiple matches for your search term, *which HTTP status code accompanied your matches*?

The answer is almost certainly that you got back a [200 OK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1).

The key idea is in the spec

> The 200 (OK) status code indicates that the request has succeeded.
> The payload sent in a 200 response depends on the request method.
> For the methods defined by this specification, the intended meaning
> of the payload can be summarized as:
>
> GET a representation of the target resource

Let's take a look at your contingency plan

> if more than 1 record is found, we have to ask the consumer api to send more info to find out correct record.

OK, so how would we do this on the web?  We'd probably send back to the browser a form, describing the extra information that we need to resolve the ambiguity.  We'd probably be sending the form with a `GET` action, meaning that we are trying to get the client to request a *different* resource.

If we are encouraging the client to ask for something more specific, that implies that we think the client asked for the wrong thing, and can correct its own error.  That tells us we are looking for something from the [4xx class of status codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5).

[404 Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) is a perfectly reasonable way to communicate to the client (and the intermediary components) "we can't find a representation of the resource you asked for right now, you should ask for a different resource."

If you can't persuade yourself that `404` is reasonable, then you should probably fall back on [400 Bad Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1); none of the other entries in the [Status Code Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) are really suitable.

[300 Multiple Choices](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.1) is a really interesting idea, but I think it's wrong for the semantics you describe

> Redirection that offers a choice of matching resources, each capable of representing the original request target, as in the 300 (Multiple Choices) status code.

I say semantically wrong, because it sounds like your circumstance is two different concepts that happen to overlap, rather than two different representations of a single concept.

Thinking about it in web terms: if I ask for Bob's home page, and you offer me a choice between Bob's work home page and his school home page, that might be `300 Multiple Choices`.  But if you are offering me a choice between Bob Smith's home page and Bob MacRoberston's home page, that probably isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I found a list of all the HTTP status codes from the golang package http.

Hopefully this list can help you indicate which one you want to use.

Here's the link: https://golang.org/src/net/http/status.go

EDIT: maybe something like StatusMultipleChoices (300 status code)?

Comment: Another code to check is 303 See Other. The [W3C standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) defines this code as returning a response with a link so the client can invoke it and, in this case of this question, "refine" search based on the contents of the link response.

Comment: Thanks for response, i will look into them .. but 300 range is for redirection .. and will see if it fits my scenario

Answer (score 0):

A new http-API?

If not: your status code should be only 200 OK on success. 4xx codes are in meaning: such site/services do not exist! (not the data is not existing) and 5xx codes are technically errors, meaning, your database is broken down or a script does intern wrong work.

So:
Request is ok: status 200 OK

Image/css/html,... file not found or servicename does not exist, you are not authorized and many more that do not give the wanted answer: status 4xx (the error comes mostly from Browser-URL/client-side)

Serverscripts internally wrong/broken: status 5xx (this error is on serverside)

3xx codes are for general URL infos like moving page (old URL - new URL), 1xx status code more in meaning of: how to communicate from browser to server and vice versa.

Please have in mind, status codes are for the whole world wide web, not for one service/server only, so they must be general.

The rest of the work is to do in your API.

Please excuse my english, you are using 404 as answer, if there is no such data in your database, i want to figure out to you, that 4xx is every time service-related, not data-related. If it is ok to ask for this data, the status must be 200 OK and the answer is: zero, none, null, nil, empty object - whatever it means ;-)

Comment: The 400 range of codes aren't for "not existing site/services" - they are to show that an error occurred because of client input.

Comment: No, this is wrong, 1 means how to communicate, 2 means it is ok to ask for, 3 means please ask another people, 4 means I can't answer, do not have this tool and 5 means please excuse me, i am broken.

Comment: This is patently incorrect. W3 is quite clear on this: "The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the client seems to have erred" - https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Ok, but in context to the question: 4xx is wrong. My english isn't good enough to write everything in complete. The complete 4xx codes aren't the answer of the question. It's irrelevant in my opinion, if 4 means I do not have this tool or you are not permitted to ask for - the response with 4xx is: you do not get an answer!

Comment: I'm not saying that 4XX is the correct answer for OP. However, you maintaining in your post that, categorically, 4XX is for missing information is incorrect and has the potential to mislead readers of your answer. I'd suggest you edit your answer to avoid that and provide accurate information information to the community

Comment: Good guy. This helps to answer the question.